Google pubsub maxMessages flow control setting is not working as expected
I'm using the "@google-cloud/pubsub": "4.7.2 Node.JS library with a pull subscription to my pubsub topic.
I am trying to control the number of messages that are processed at any one time, so I don't overload our database and server resources.
I've setup a simple test where I put a 20 second delay in the processing of the messages like this so I can simulate super long running process.
const messageHandler = async (message) => {
  try {
      const decodedData = Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString('utf8');
      const data = JSON.parse(decodedData);

      await ProcessWorkflow(data)
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 20000));
      message.ack(); // Acknowledge successful processing

  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error processing workflow:', error);

  
      if (isTransientError(error)) {
          message.nack(); 
      } else {
          message.ack(); 
      }
  }
}; 

I define the subscriber options like this:
const subscriberOptions = {
  flowControl: {
    maxMessages: maxWorkflowMessages,
  },
};

now, if I put the maxWorkflowMessages =1, and publish 10 messages, it correctly processes 1 message every 20 seconds.
however, if I set this value = 2, what I see is that it processes 4 messages at a time.
if I set the value = 3, it is then processing 9 messages at time.
I was expecting it would limit the messages retrieved = maxmessages, but it looks like it's using a factor here...does this make sense? Is this a bug?

Hi @mike Hennessy, Could you check this stack link ? let me know if this is helpful for you or not.

That doesn't' really help. I think my test shows that the maxMessages on flowControl setting is not a linear setting. Meaning, if you set this number to 4, it doesn't restrict message flow to 4 unacked messages. It sets it to 16 unack messeages.
It uses the factor of whatever number you set here. This seems to be a bug to me and/or it should be documented how that number actually works.

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
